# Запуск кода kotlin в vs code непонятные символы

Tags: кодировка, консоль, visual-studio-code

При выполнении кода в VsCode вместо текста символы [image: Скрин]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19837

Comment: в визуал студио стоит кодировка utf-8

Comment: И? Кодировка исходного кода никак не связана с кодировкой терминала.

Comment: Хрустальный шар мне подсказывает, что там написано что-то типа `"kotlinc" не является внешней или внутренней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом`. То есть либо kotlin вообще не установлен, либо путь к нему не прописан в переменную окружения PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно скачать kotlin compiler с сайта котлин или из гитхаб. Добавить пару bin в path подобно Java и готово

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]